# MS Word not embedding Math font

Tags: microsoft-word, embedded-fonts

I have created a document with two bespoke fonts (company fonts). I have set Word to embed fonts so maintain the look of the document when it is distributed outside of the company, and the main body font embeds fine. However, the Math font used for the equation does not embed properly. The font looks fine on my machine, it is when it is sent to a machine which doesn't have the font installed.

[image]

The Math font is an OpenType font

Comment: http://mrchasemath.wordpress.com/2013/01/05/math-fonts-in-microsoft-office/ and http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/officeversion_other-word/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-mathematics-font-in/14838264-dd51-4641-87f5-cba5e81b6fae

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't that clear. The font displays fine on my machine, its when the document is opened on a machine without the math font installed that it goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If this document is for distribution outside your offices, you probably want to make it a (non-editable) PDF file. Free tools, such as the Nitro PDF reader, will add a PDF "printer driver" visible from all Print dialogs. Just "Print" your Word document to "PDF", rather than the office printer This has pros and cons, depending on whether you wnat the recipient to be able to change the text.

An alternative is to take a screenshot of the equations in your document, and insert the *image* of the formula. That does not require font embedding, but the equation cannot be edited afterwards.

Comment: The docs have to be Word docs not PDFs to meet contractual requirements. I would like them to remain as actual equations. There is an option within Word that will convert the equations to images without having to screenshot them myself but have avoided that because it looks bad.